# Why can I only use color and background in wp.customize?

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress

In my wordpress theme, the output of the following Javascript code works, but the control says, whenever it's not a color or a background, that it is a syntax error. I've been trying to find a solution for hours and nothing seems to remove the syntax errors unless I remove the line. I would have to remove border-bottom and border-top but I need it for my color scheme. What am I doing wrong?

I've only added a short piece of my code, as the rest is repetitive or not relevant.

```
    wp.customize( 'nlmc_color_scheme', function( value ) {
            value.bind( function( to ) {

                    if ( 'inverse' === to ) {
                            $( 'hr' ).css({
                                    color: '#fff',
                                    background: '#000',
                                    border-bottom: '1px solid #303030',
                                    border-top: '1px solid #000'
                            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to set the CSS that way, you should avoid the "-" and do it in the following style:

```
 $( 'hr' ).css({
     color: '#fff',
     background: '#000',
     borderBottom: '1px solid #303030',
     borderTop: '1px solid #000'
 });
```

Or you can wrap the properties in quotation marks, so that border-bottom becomes "border-bottom" etc.

About the "why?":

> Also, jQuery can equally interpret the CSS and DOM formatting of
>   multiple-word properties. For example, jQuery understands and returns
>   the correct value for both .`css({ "background-color": "#ffe",
>   "border-left": "5px solid #ccc" })` and `.css({backgroundColor: "#ffe",
>   borderLeft: "5px solid #ccc" })`. **Notice that with the DOM notation,
>   quotation marks around the property names are optional, but with CSS
>   notation they're required due to the hyphen in the name.**
>
> *(Taken from http://api.jquery.com/css/#css-properties)*

Comment: @user3011751 Great! :) If you can confirm that this solves your problem, please accept it, so that others can recognize that this is a real solution.

Answer (score 0):

ok try using inspect element in Google chrome (right hand click then inspect element) then install "WP Editor" that way you can identify exactly where it is and fix it.

Comment: also could you supply more code, or even a live URL and I may how to fix the problem for you.